# SSH client seems to be checking '/dev/null' instead of 'known_hosts' file when checking remote server's ECDSA key

Tags: ssh, openssh, key-authentication

I'd like to know why my `known_hosts` file doesn't seem to be checked correctly while using SSH. In short, my guess is that my SSH client is checking `/dev/null` instead of the `known_hosts` file. Details on how I guessed that are written below.

For my example, I'm logging in from a node named `mars` into a client node named `saturn`. I can get into `saturn` after setting up the public and private keys, but I get this warning:

```
root@mars# ssh saturn
Warning: Permanently added 'saturn,10.30.3.3' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

When I logged out and logged in to the same `saturn` node, I got the same warning message. It doesn't matter how many times I log out and log back in, I get this message. I don't want to suppress the warning. I want to know why this warning keeps appearing. I checked if my `known_hosts` file in the `mars` node has the `saturn`'s ECDSA key by doing the following, but I get an error:

```
# ssh-keygen -F saturn
do_known_hosts: hostkeys_foreach failed: No such file or directory
```

I wondered if the `known_hosts` file is not checked correctly while using the SSH client, so logged in with the verbosity flags to check where things went wrong. Below is a truncated output:

```
root@mars# ssh -vvv saturn
.
.(truncated)
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:nkvxyuLtlDdO8pAycafcfqSPE7OUWgN6Z++Aia/Cygg
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/dev/null"
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/dev/null"
Warning: Permanently added 'saturn,10.33.3.3' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
.
.(truncated)
```

So, it seems like my SSH client on `mars` is looking into `/dev/null` for the known hosts key, instead of `/root/.ssh/known_hosts`.

I wanted to see what a "good" behavior looks like, so I used SSH on a different pair of servers (here named `earth` and `neptune`) that I already know does not give me the `Warning: Permanently added` message. I've turned on verbosity and I'm only showing a portion of the log messages. Logging in from `earth` to `neptune` gives:

```
root@earth# ssh -vvv neptune
.
. (truncated)
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:qo7vcBwG53p/9MlaTIQJbMZ8Wgf6QxiCJLR1jUiblQ8
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from saturn
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.33.9.10
debug1: Host 'neptune' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:9
.
.(truncated)
```

From the above, I can see that `earth` correctly checks `/root/.ssh/known_hosts`. Another confirmation that the key is found in `known_hosts` in this "good" scenario:

```
root@earth# ssh-keygen -F neptune
# Host neptune found: line 7
```

**In summary, does anyone know why the `Warning` message keeps appearing, and if the SSH client is indeed checking `/dev/null` instead of `known_hosts`?** If my guess is correct, how might the client be fixed so that the message doesn't reappear?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and this SSH client version on all nodes:

```
root@mars:~# ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you check if there is a known_hosts file in that location ... can you touch one if it's not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only explanation that comes to mind is that the [SSH client configuration](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/ssh_config.5.html) either on this machine or on this account has been modified to not remember known public keys in a `known_hosts` file. Check the settings for `GlobalKnownHostsFile` and `UserKnownHostsFile` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*` and `~/.ssh/config`.

This may have been done to increase privacy, so that other administrators on the machine (or people who manage to compromise the machine or its backups in the future) can't see where you've connected to unless they spy on the connection. For the `known_hosts` file, this is not a very good compromise between privacy and security: having to check the peer's public key manually each time is error-prone (in addition to being inconvenient). Turning on the `HashKnownHosts` option gives a decent amount of privacy with a decent amount of functionality: with this option turned on, it's impossible to directly list the entries in a `known_hosts` file, all you can do is guess what the entry might be and check your guess (and each check is somewhat costly, so you can't brute-force a very large number of potential server names).

Comment: Indeed, the file `/root/.ssh/config` contained `UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null`. Changing it to `/root/.ssh/known_hosts` fixed my original issue. After reading this answer, I found that the explanation for `UserKnownHostsFile` and other config options for the SSH client reside in the man page ssh_config(5). Might be useful for other beginners.